# How to Fix an Encryption Error in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I would like to connect to an on premise sql server from Power BI Desktop.  So, I did the following steps:

1. Open Power BI Desktop
2. Click **Get Data** icon.
3. Select **Database > SQL Server database**
4. Type **Server** name and **Database** name
5. Got this error message below:

[image]

I would like to have an encrypted connection here.  So why does the message occur?  How do I fix it?

Comment: You must configure the SQL Server and enable the encrypted connections. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16